# I can't play music. Is there a problem on the discord side?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am now facing an error like this.

```
future: <Task finished name='Task-82' coro=<VoiceClient._create_socket() done, defined at /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/voice_client.py:172> exception=gaierror(7, 'No address associated with hostname')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/files/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/voice_client.py", line 191, in _create_socket
    self.endpoint_ip = socket.gethostbyname(self.endpoint)
socket.gaierror: [Errno 7] No address associated with hostname
```

When I try to play music with my bot on discord, it times out with this error.
Is anyone in the same situation as me?
Please tell me how to resolve.
pip has all updated.  python3.8.5.
It could be used until the day.  The code has not changed at all.  I don't think it's the cause

```
pip 20.2.1
pip discord 1.0.1
pip discord.py 1.3.4
pip youtube-dl 2020.7.28
pip PyNaCl 1.4.0
pip asyncio 3.4.3
pip ffmpeg 1.4
```

Comment: Was your code working previously? Which discord.py version are you using?

Comment: I'm sorry, I edited

Answer (score 1):

The issue you have is related to this PR here. https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/pull/5188

It will be fixed in 1.4.